# How to do gzip most efficiently in express react app made using nextjs framework and hosted on heroku

Tags: reactjs, express, heroku, gzip, next.js

I have hosted a nextjs app with custom express server on heroku at https://nextherokuapp.herokuapp.com. I want to optimize its speed. One of the recommendation Google speed test gave is to enable text compression. So I used compression middleware

This is the code of compression middleware I used

const compression = require('compression');
const express = require('express');

...

const server = express();
server.use(compression());

But the google speed test recommends further text compression will increase page load by 6 seconds.

So my question is what further can I do to compress text and increase page loading speed.

Answer (score 0):

It should be possible to enable gzip compression using a custom nginx buildpack in front of your NextJS app.

```
$ heroku buildpacks:add heroku-community/nginx
```

Add the build pack and create a file `config/nginx.config.erb` with a config like this:

```
http {
    gzip on;
    gzip_comp_level 2;
    gzip_min_length 512;

  server {
    listen <%= ENV["PORT"] %>;
    server_name _;
    keepalive_timeout 5;

    location / {

      <% if ENV['NGINX_SKIP_HTTPS_PROXY'] == 'true' %>
        if ($http_x_forwarded_proto != "https") {
          return 301 https://$host$request_uri;
        }
      <% end %>

      proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-For $proxy_add_x_forwarded_for;
      proxy_set_header Host $http_host;
      proxy_redirect off;
      proxy_pass http://localhost:3000; #next serve listens here and receives nginx requests
    }
  }
}
```

You can find the full configuration details in [this post](https://pulkitgoyal.in/ssl-nextjs-deployment-on-heroku).